# GLSL versions compatibility

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, shader

I have shaders which work with GLES 3.0:

```
#version 300 es

#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

in vec2 v_tex_coord;
uniform sampler2D s_texture;
uniform vec4 u_color;

out vec4 fragmentColor;

void main()
{
    fragmentColor = texture(s_texture, v_tex_coord)*u_color;
}
```

I'd like them to work with OpenGL 4.1 (not ES).
Does there exist a way to declare both ES and desktop versions in one shader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use a prefix string. `glShaderSource` takes an array of strings, which will conceptually be concatenated together before processing. So you will need to remove the `#version` declaration from your shader files and put the version declaration into a string that is generated at runtime. Something like this:

```
GLuint CreateShader(const std::string &shader)
{
  GLuint shaderName = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

  const GLchar *strings[2];
  if(IS_USING_GLES)
    strings[0] = "#version 300 es";
  else
    strings[0] = "#version 410 core\n";

  strings[1] = (const GLchar*)shader.c_str();
  glShaderSource(shaderName, 2, strings, NULL);

  //Compile your shader and check for errors.

  return shaderName;
}
```

Your runtime should know whether it's ES or desktop GL.

Also, there is no need for that `ifdef` around your `precision` statement. Precision declarations have been part of desktop GL for a while, well before 4.1. Though admittedly, they don't actually do anything ;)